# learning php oop - can't reverse array

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning PHP OOP and Im trying to understand why the following script doesn't work:

```
class ShowTimeline {
    var $conn;
    var $rev;

    function getTimeline ($conn) {
        return $this->conn;
    }

    function reverseTimeline () {
        $rev = array_reverse($this->conn, false);
        return $rev;
    }

    function display () {
        $this->reverseTimeline();
        print_r($this->rev);
    }
}
print '<hr />';
$connect = new showTimeline();
$connect->conn = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$connect->display();
```

When I change the script to:

```
//same stuff above
function display () {
            $this->reverseTimeline();
            print_r($this->conn); //changed from $this->rev
        }
//same stuff below
```

I get the print out:

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three )
```

which is correct. Please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access class' parameters with `$this->`.

```
function reverseTimeline () {
    $this->rev = array_reverse($this->conn, false);
    return $this->rev;
}
```

Using just `$rev` it is treated as a local variable.

Comment: that's great thanks - how do I know if something is a class parameter? Is it through the var call at the start of the class?

Comment: You define class' properties by your own. However I advise you to use `public`/`protected`/`private` modifiers instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `$rev`, you're actually assigning to a local variable, not the `$rev` in your object.  `$this->rev` never gets set.

Change your `$rev`s to `$this->rev`, and things should start working.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually set $this->rev to the reversed array.

```
function reverseTimeline () {
            $rev = array_reverse($this->conn, false);
            $this->rev = $rev;
       }

function display () {
            $this->reverseTimeline();
            print_r($this->rev);
        }
```

would do it.